# Failing to build Boost 1.60.0 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I've used the [Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) that is provided from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).

Many of the existing problems with somewhat related nature seem to occur within Visual Studio and be due to faulty project settings and linking in particular.

My problems lies in actually getting Boost to build using the 
 [Developer Command Prompt for VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and running it as admin.

First I just extracted the folder and ran the VS2015 command prompt from the root folder with

```
bootstrap.bat
```

which gave me the following output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_60_0>bootstrap.bat
Building Boost.Build engine

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.
```

According to the *bootstrap.log* a lot of required header files were not found. According to the [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx) the headers, sources and librares is now distributed on a different location on the user machines. This happend to me! I had  to move a ton of headers and lib files from  for it to find them.

However..... I can't figure out how to go on from this point.

Comment: it seems to be related to platform, i.e. 32bit or 64bit. Make sure that you are running the correct command prompt

Comment: @Default That was it! I ran the (VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt) located in the (Visual Studio Tools) directory and it worked! Boost is up and running! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your output at the end there are 4 suspicious warnings:

> ..\kernel32.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
>   ..\advapi32.lib: warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
>   ..\user32.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
>   ..\uuid.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Note the machine type, i.e. it probably related to which platform this is running for. Visual Studio Command Prompts come in different forms, make sure that you are running the correct one - In your case the correct one seems to be the **VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt**